# How to split based on an alphabet?

Tags: python

I am trying to split based on an alphabet as below but somehow doesn't work,I have the current and expected output ,what am I doing wrong?how to fix it?

```
chiprev = ['4355b3','4364a1','4278b3']

for rev in chiprev:
    print rev.split("[a-b][A-B]")[-1]
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
4355b3
4364a1
4278b3
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
b3
a1
b3
```

Comment: `str.split()` splits on exact match, not a regular expression.  Did you want [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)?

Comment: I tried as `re.split(r'[a-f]+',rev)` ,it  outputs as `['4355', '3']
['4364', '1']
['4278', '3']`

Comment: try this: `re.split(r'([a-f]+.)', '1234c5')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in chiprev:
    print(i[re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]',i).start():])
```

Out:

```
b3
a1
b3
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses the [`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) regular expression operation.

In words, it is essentially taking each `rev`, finding all sub-pieces that begin with `a-b` (downcased) or `A-B` (uppercase), hence the `|` operator. The `+` signifies to also extract whatever follows. This will allow the search to also extract the numbers that follow the letter.

```
chiprev = ['4355b3','4364a1','4278b3']

for rev in chiprev:
    print re.search(r'([a-b]|[A-B]).+',rev).group()
```

Output:

```
b3
a1
b3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split using a regex on either `ab` or `AB` and therefore could use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re%20split#re.split)

The regex that you use `[a-b][A-B]` will not give the expected output because it matches 2 ranges, a-b lowercase and A-B uppercase which does not find a match in your example data because it contains only a single `a` or `b`

If you are trying to split on a lower or uppercase alphabet a-z, you could make use of the flag `re.IGNORECASE`. As a regex, you could use a capturing group as the capturing group is returned.

`([a-z][0-9]+)`

That will match

- `(` Capturing group

  - `[a-z]` Match single character a-z
  - `[0-9]+` Match 1+ times a digit (omit the `+` to match a single digit)
- `)` Close capturing group

From the result take the second field. For example:

```
import re
chiprev = ['4355b3','4364a1', '4278b3']
for rev in chiprev:
    print (re.split("([a-z][0-9]+)", rev, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1])
```

Result

```
b3
a1
b3
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/bFosDL)